# Deleting events in Google Calander API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

Google has no documentation for how to remove an event in node.JS

I have been able to add new events to my calendar using the following code:

```
    calendar.events.insert({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: event,
    }, function(err, event) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' +      err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
});
```

I have been fiddling around with this for 4 hours now, and am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

To delete an event just call the delete method. The following code can be found on the Node.js GitHub repo for the Google API

```
  delete: function (params, callback) {
  var parameters = {
    options: {
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/{calendarId}',
      method: 'DELETE'
    },
    params: params,
    requiredParams: ['calendarId'],
    pathParams: ['calendarId'],
    context: self
  };

  return createAPIRequest(parameters, callback);
}
```

From : https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/b08ce4189e6b2efdc7cf3e7c3bdb3cbabb08da8c/apis/calendar/v3.js

**If you wanted it as a function:**

First get the eventId of the event you want to delete then call the method below with that eventId

```
function deleteEvent(eventId) {

      var params = {
        calendarId: 'primary',
        eventId: eventId,
      };

      calendar.events.delete(params, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Event deleted.');
      });
    }
```

Comment: I get an error about for the line "calendar.events.delete which says "Missing name after . operator. ". Any suggestions?

Comment: can i send note or reason to delete the event in above example we are sending params with calenarId and EventId can we send note or reason to cancel the event

Answer (score 5):

I hope it helps someone with the same problem/question.

```
function deleteEvent(event_id) {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.delete({
            'calendarId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'eventId': event_id
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
            if(response.error || response == false){
                alert('Error');
            }
            else{
                alert('Success');               
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a function to delete more than one events?

Answer (score 0):

below code work for me to delete event from google calendar from nodejs.

```
    const {google} = require("googleapis")
    const oauth2client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
           google_client_id,
           google_client_secret,
           redirect_url // for ex. http://localhost:3000
    )

    const calendar = google.calendar("v3");        
    oauth2client.setCredentials({refresh_token:user_refresh_token})
    //you can access user refresh token while he logged in first time using google
    await calendar.events.delete({
        auth: oauth2client,
        calendarId: 'primary',
        eventId: eventId //eventId you will get while creating event.
    });
```